# Angular giving Syntax Error during initial configuration

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to create an Angular application on a Windows 10 OS. Previously when I attempted to install Node.js and NPM I was getting 'Cannot find 'resolve' of undefined'. I solved it by downgrading my Node.js to 6.17 and the NPM to 3.10. I can now download the Angular CLI but when I use the 'new' command, I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng:23
  );
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
```

When I open the file location I get the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

// Provide a title to the process in `ps`.
// Due to an obscure Mac bug, do not start this title with any symbol.
try {
  process.title = 'ng ' + Array.from(process.argv).slice(2).join(' ');
} catch (_) {
  // If an error happened above, use the most basic title.
  process.title = 'ng';
}

// This node version check ensures that extremely old versions of node are not used.
// These may not support ES2015 features such as const/let/async/await/etc.
// These would then crash with a hard to diagnose error message.
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-var-keyword
var version = process.versions.node.split('.').map(part => Number(part));
if (version[0] < 10 || version[0] === 11 || (version[0] === 10 && version[1] < 13)) {
  process.stderr.write(
    'Node.js version ' + process.version + ' detected.\n' +
    'The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.\n\n' +
    'Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.\n',
  );

  process.exit(3);
}

require('../lib/init');
```

It's complaining about the parentheses for the if statement. I tried getting rid of the parentheses and it only makes the situation worse. What would be the best way to go about solving this situation. WOuld it be better to use somehow install a new version of Node and work around the 'resolve' error or take with what I have with the version at hand?

Comment: The latest `angular-cli` requires `nodejs 12+`. Try to completely remove `cli` and `nodejs` and reinstall them.